# Converting a curve into a mesh does not copy over shape keys

Tags: modeling, animation, mesh, bezier-curves, shape-keys

Currently, I have a shape key for a curve that allows this coil to stretch.
Using the object menu, converting the curve to a mesh removes the shape key,
How do I preserve the shape key when converting the curve to a mesh?
[image: The coil as a curve, shape keys in tact]

[image: Demonstrasion of the shape key.]

[image: Conversion of the curve to a mesh]

[image: The curve is now a mesh, shape keys have gone missing]

Comment: I guess it's not possible, the curve loses its shape keys...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't preserve them simply.

What you can do is make multiple copies of the mesh, each from a different shapekey, and then join as shapes.

1. Make a copy of your curve object for each shapekey.  For each copy, set the value of one shapekey for the curve to 1.0 (or pin that shapekey.)
2. Select all of your curve objects and convert to mesh.
3. With all objects still selected, make sure your "basis" object is the active selection.  From the shapekey specials menu (the triangle to the right of your mesh's empty list of shapekeys, on properties/object data) select "join as shapes".

You can now delete all of the duplicates.  The original has all the other shapekeys as mesh-based shapekeys.