# Keep Shape Keys After Modifier was Apply

Tags: modifiers, shape-keys

I wanted to duplicate a body mesh and remove some parts of it to make it look like a shirt, and that's almost done. Now the mesh look like a shirt but I needed to add a Wireframe modifier so it turns into a fishnet, now just like that, everything must be done.

This model has to be exported as a FBX and be used in Unity, Unity didn't show the shape keys *Blendshapes* and that's because of the modifier. All I need to do is apply the modifier, but the modifier didn't want to be applied because of the shape keys, it throws an error saying "modifier cannot be applied to a mesh with shape keys".

I found an add-on that let's you apply a modifier with shape keys, this one: https://github.com/przemir/ApplyModifierForObjectWithShapeKeys but honestly the result of the modifier being applied is not what I really wanted. I prefer the result of the modifier without the application, and I found a way to do so: the convert > mesh function, but it doesn't keep my shape keys.

I saw this forum [Converting a curve into a mesh does not copy over shape keys](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/235088/converting-a-curve-into-a-mesh-does-not-copy-over-shape-keys) and it kinda did what I wanted, but remember how the end results of the applied modifier isn't really appealing, well it's being transformed into the Join as Shapes...

I just need the results of the modifier without applying it, and keeping the shape keys. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not experienced with Unity, but if FBX protects Shapekeys and Unity can use it ... it should be working in this order ...

- *Duplicate* object with the *Wire* modifier and the *Shapekey*
- Set *Shapekey* to 1
- *Convert to Mesh*
  (This applies modifier and shapekey.)
- Select original object with *Basis* key shape and also *Convert to Mesh*
  (so the modifier became apply and shapekeys deleted in one action)
- Select both objects with Base shape *Active* and search for *Join as Shape*

[image]

If this doesnt result with expected result for you ... you would have to share screens or blend file with your specific issue.